# Dynamic analysis of Swift application using Cycript or GDB

Tags: ios, swift, security

I am doing analysis of some Swift iOS application , I am able to attach gdb or Cycript , but after that these tools are not able to do any method swizzling.
I cant even call some method directly using cycript , which is very easy in Objective C apps.
In GDB , I can set the breakpoint on the methods , but its not able to detect the same method while execution.
If there is some way for runtime analysis of swift app , please let me know.

Comment: This might be better in http://security.stackexchange.com/